# Why should we use webapi keys

Tags: http, api-key

Why should we generate api keys for domains to use web api when we have the referrer to check the source of the request?

Comment: No one would *ever* forge the referrer on an HTTP packet...

Answer (score 2):

The value of HTTP_REFERER can easily be faked. If you want to verify that somebody (or some website) is really entitled to access a service, you have to involve some sort of authentication, which generally means an API key (or for people, a username/password).

Comment: What's this crazy correct spelling of REFERRER? (http://gadgetopia.com/post/2687)

Comment: oh yeah, I didn't even notice that. Now "fixed" ;-)

Comment: if the api key is for some JS Api like google's then anybody can see what api key you are using.. and he also can use the same api key.. then whats the use of generating a key against a domain

Comment: I'd have to see an example, but from what you're describing it sounds like in that case there's nothing to stop you from taking and using the API key. Google (or whoever) might have checks in place to make it difficult, but they can't make it impossible.

Comment: say only registered users generate keys. and system assigns key for domain to user then still why cant system assign only domain to user instead of key

Answer (score -1):

Some browsers don't send `REFERER` headers.